# What's the difference between 'mvn clean' and 'Clicking intelliJ's maven pannel: clean'?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfgp3.jpg)

It's normal when Clicking IJ's maven pannel;
It's unnormal when I coded "mvn clean" in terminal .

What's the difference?

Comment: what do you mean by "unnormal"?

Comment: not normal:errors happened

Answer (score 0):

There should be no any difference. The result should be the same if you type "mvn clean" in terminal (directory must be same as your project), o you click in Intellij Maven Lifecycle "clean".

Comment: The result is no.

Comment: Try to check maven version. Are you using same maven version as in intellij?. By default intellij is using Bundle maven version. When you execute 'mvn clean' in you console, then the maven is used from your installed maven.